# How do I input integers into an array using cin with each digit being separated by commas?

Tags: c++

I am having trouble using `cin` to enter multiple single digits that are separated by a comma.
So far i have tried using this

```
int size = 8;
// = {2,5,6,7,8,3,1,4} the values I wish to input
int nums[8];
cin >> nums [0] >> nums [1] >> nums [2] >> nums [3] >> nums [4] >> nums [5] >> nums [6] >> nums [7];
for (int i=0; i < 8; i++) {
    cout << nums[i] << " ";
}
```

When I input `2,5,6,7,8,3,1,4`, only `2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0` is outputted.
Is there any way to fix this by using `cin`?

Comment: You can read `csv` files using `fstream` and passing the delimiter as `,` You can also use `strtok` API to parse values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  getline to read entire string and then iterate through it.
String text;

```
getline(cin, text);
```

Or

```
while(!cin.eof()){ cin>>x>>y; arr[i]=x; i++; }
```

Comment: It is so bad. You are using `cin` twice! Also `wile(!cin.eof())` is considered very bad. Instead use it directly: `while(cin >> x >> y)`.

Comment: How will you detect the end of stream ? cin.eof is to detect end of stream and exit from the loop. Otherwise, your loop will never end.